# HTA how do I get the username for the current user?

Tags: vba, vbscript, hta

I want to get the username for the current user and then create a link in my application name

the link would look like

```
http://localhost/?id=username
```

I tried

```
Dim objNetworkSet 
objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
```

But it's not supported in HTA applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's prefix indicates, "objNetwork" is an object. So use "Set" to assign to the variable.

```
   Dim objNetwork : Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
   MsgBox objNetwork.UserName
```

Assuming you want to set the link at runtime/on the fly:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>SetLink HTA</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="SetLink HTA"
  >
  <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
   Sub SetLink()
     Dim oWNet : Set oWNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
     MsgBox oWNet.UserName
     LinkToBeDone.href = "http://gent/~" & oWNet.UserName
   End Sub
  </SCRIPT>
 </head>
  <body onLoad="SetLink">
   <a id="LinkToBeDone" href="!somewhere!">To your home at a real computer</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

P.S. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727047/error-reported-on-a-blank-line) for the same mistake. Seems to be a bad day for this feature of VBScript.

Comment: how do I insert it into a link?