# Error reported on a blank line

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am truly stumped this afternoon and have done quite a bit of searching to no avail. I am getting the error

"Object doesn't support this property or method /admin/Upload1_20120508JB.asp, line 91"

From the following code:

```
        90 wf = fso2.CreateTextFile(sWriteFilePath)
        91 
        92 If fso1.FileExists(sReadFilePath) Then ...
```

Line 91 is blank and Line 90 works as expected, the file gets created in the proper location. Has anyone seen anything like this before? If so, what was the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Has fso1 and fso2 been declared properly? (there isn't a lot to go on)

Comment: try chunking through the code - i.e. comment out most of it and uncomment lines until you hit a problem

Comment: I have been chunking away at it for a while. When I eliminate the blank line I get the error on the FileExists line. set fso1 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use **Set**, when you assign an object to a variable.

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10725000/603855) to realize that today is a bad day for this feature of VBScript.)

Comment: I did use set - set fso1 = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). Must I use Set for wf? Set wf = fso2.CreateTextFile(sWriteFilePath)?

Comment: Holy cow my ASP chops are rusty - you were absolutely correct.